# Xamarin.Forms how display internet connection CHANGED?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Structure of my app:

```
public partial class App : Application
  {

    public App()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      MainPage = new MdpMainPage();
    }
```

MdpMainPage is a MasterDetailPage:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <pages:HomePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

My HomePage is a CarouselPage and it contains three pages of type ContentPage.

```
<CarouselPage>
    ...some namespaces...
    <CarouselPage.Children>
        <pages:HomePageA />
        <pages:HomePageB />
        <pages:HomePageC />
    </CarouselPage.Children>
</CarouselPage>
```

I would like to use JamesMontemagno's ConnectivityPlugin to **WATCH for internet connection CHANGES.**


 DisplayAlert box should pop up **when the application starts** and it should tell us either:

```
DisplayAlert("Internet connection found.", "Wait for the application data to update.", "OK");
```

...or...

```
DisplayAlert("No internet connection found.", "Application data may not be up to date. Connect to a working network.", "OK");
```

If there **was internet connection at the start** of the application and **it gets lost during the using of the app**, another message box should pop up saying:

```
DisplayAlert("Internet connection lost.", "Application data may not be up to date. Connect to a working network.", "OK");
```

If there **was no internet connection at the start** of the application and somehow **later the device connects successfully**, the firstly mentioned message box should appear:

```
DisplayAlert("Internet connection found.", "Wait for the application data to update.", "OK");
```

I've tried to figure out the correct implementation with the help of the provided [Documentation](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/ConnectivityChanges.html).

Unfortunately, James Montemagno doesn't bother to **explain in detail** how to use the ConnectivityPlugin, so beginners like myself tend to end up confused.

I know I should use the following code snippets:

```
/// <summary>
/// Event handler when connection changes
/// </summary>
event ConnectivityChangedEventHandler ConnectivityChanged; 


public class ConnectivityChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public bool IsConnected { get; set; }
}

public delegate void ConnectivityChangedEventHandler(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e);

CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += async (sender, args) =>
{
  Debug.WriteLine($"Connectivity changed to {args.IsConnected}");
};
```

...but I **don't know where to put them**.

I've tried a couple of combinations, but to no avail so far.

Do I put some in the App.xaml and some in the MasterDetailPage?

Or rather one of the Detail pages?

Or in each of the detail pages?

Please don't think I didn't google around. Because I did and everybody seems to have a different opinion on how to flavor the basic Montemagno recipe, which is very confusing.

Could somebody provide the simplest, cleanest way to implement this? Nothing fancy really, just message boxes that inform the user about changes in connectivity.

Help would be much appreciated.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a dozen pages in your application. It wouldn't make sense to have connectivity code in all of them. A better place to subscribe to the events would be your `App.xaml.cs` inside the `OnStart` method (could also be inside the constructor). This is what I have in one of the projects:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        MessagingService.Current.SendMessage("connectivityChanged", args.IsConnected);
    };
}
```

[MessagingService](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/xamarin.forms-toolkit/wiki/Services) is from James Montemagno's Xamarin.Forms Toolkit but you can also use Xamarin's [Messaging Center](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/).

Then, on each ViewModel of those pages that want to subscribe to this message of a connection change will subscribe to it like this:

```
MessagingService.Current.Subscribe ("connectivityChanged", async (e) => 
{
    //Show a dialog or something to inform about the connectivity change.
});
```

This way you'll have everything decoupled.

---

**Edit:** I just noticed you're probably looking to show the alert from a code behind of the page. You could simply subscribe to the event on your `MasterDetailPage` like this:

```
public class MainPageCS : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MainPageCS() 
    {
        MessagingService.Current.Subscribe<bool>("connectivityChanged", (args, connected) =>
        {
            if (connected)
                DisplayAlert("Internet connection found.", "Wait for the application data to update.", "OK");
            else
                DisplayAlert("Internet connection lost.", "Application data may not be up to date. Connect to a working network.", "OK");
        });
    }
}
```

Any time the connectivity changes, your App.xaml.cs handles the event and sends a message to the `MessagingService` which is received by the MasterDetailPage that reacts to it.

**Edit 2:** Put this into your `App.xaml.cs` so the connection gets checked only when the app starts.

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        var isConnected = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;

        await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Connection", $"Connected {isConnected}", "OK");
    });
}
```

Comment: I downloaded Montemagno's Toolkit. I put your first snippet into App.xaml.cs into the OnStart method. I put your third snippet into my MdpMainPage.xaml.cs (which by the way serves also as the burger menu). I'm getting a weird error - the e.IsConnected is underlined with a red squiggly - IMessaging service does not contain a definition for IsConnected ...etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, it doesn't work. If there IS connection -> It doesn't show a popup at start saying "Internet connection found." If there IS NO connection -> It doesn't show a popup at start saying "Internet connection NOT found." It also doesn't show changes in connection.

Comment: @PaxForce For the first two, you jus tneed to add the following check to the first page of your application: `if(!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected) { /*We have connection*/ } else { /* No connection */ }`. Can you set a breakpoint to the third snippet so we see it actually runs? It's possible that the DisplayAlert method doesn't work as expected inside the MasterDetailPage.

Comment: If by "first page of your application" you mean HomePageA, then I can't add it there, because every time user would navigate to the home page there would be a popup, even If the connection wouldn't change. I'm going to try the break point thing you've suggested and I'll report back to you.

Comment: The answer is no, the third snippet doesn't run when it's in MasterDetailPage. I've just tried to put it inside the constructor of one of the DetailPages - doesn't run either.

Comment: @PaxForce Ok, I'll try it myself with a small project

Comment: Take a look at this pls: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/ConnectivityChanges.html

Comment: @PaxForce Okay, I had a small mistake in the code. It was very apparent when I had it open on Visual Studio. Please copy the third snippet again. The problem was that App.xaml.cs was sending a boolean value but the MasterDetailPage was expecting ConnectivityChangedEventArgs.

Comment: Awesome! The finding and losing connection works. Is it possible to utilize your snippet to also run at the start of the application once and only once?

Comment: @PaxForce Great! Check out edit 2 for a way to check if the connection exists when the application starts. `OnStart` only gets called when the application starts and never twice so it fits your requirement.